# okhttp cache-control no-cache processing strategy

Tags: http, okhttp, cache-control, no-cache, stale-if-error

I have a question about caching support in okhttp. This is a complex question, so I’ll break it into two parts.

## 1. `no-cache` processing strategy for request

I noticed that the request header `Cache-Control: no-cache`, or as okhttp calls it `CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK`, does not result in cached response validation by passing the `If-None-Match` or `If-Modified-Since` headers etc., instead of this it always results in a network request and reading the response body.

Here's what [RFC 9111](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9111#name-no-cache) says:

> 5.2.1.4. no-cache
>
> The no-cache request directive indicates that the client prefers a stored response not be used to satisfy the request without successful validation on the origin server.

The key for me here is *“without successful validation”*. That is, if the application, for instance, does not have a network, then it is prohibited to return the cached response, 'cause it cannot be validated. But if there is a network connection and the server returned `304`, then you can take the response from the cache.

There is also an informal description of the directives in [this article](https://csswizardry.com/2019/03/cache-control-for-civilians/) (mentioned in [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#see_also))

> A good use-case for no-cache would be almost any dynamic HTML page. Think of a news site’s homepage: it’s not realtime, nor does it contain any sensitive information, but ideally we’d like the page to always show the freshest content. We can use cache-control: no-cache to instruct the browser to check back with the server first, and if the server has nothing newer to offer (304), let’s reuse the cached version. In the event that the server did have some fresher content, it would respond as such (200) and send the newer file.

It says *“if the server has nothing newer to offer (304), let’s reuse the cached version”*.

Formally, the current implementation in okhttp does not contradict the RFC, but in my opinion it would be more efficient to take the response from the cache after successful validation in order to save traffic. It seems that this would be indistinguishable behavior from the current one, with the only difference being that the bytes would not be transferred over the network once again.

- **Is this a conscious decision?**
- **Are there any hidden motives behind the current implementation?**
- **What `Cache-Control` value can be currently used for a traffic saving use case?**

## 2. `Cache-Control` directive for using a cached response when there is no network

It would be great to have a following strategy: try to validate the cached response on origin server, if the server responds that it's still valid (304), then use it, but if there is no network, then you can use the cached response. This would make it easier to implement offline support in mobile apps.

The most suitable directive for this purpose is `stale-if-error` ([RFC 5861](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5861#section-4) and the same [article](https://csswizardry.com/2019/03/cache-control-for-civilians/)).

> The stale-if-error Cache-Control extension indicates that when an error is encountered, a cached stale response MAY be used to satisfy the request, regardless of other freshness information.

- **Do you have any plans to add support for `stale-if-error`?**
- **Are you open to pull requests on this?**
- **Is there already a way to implement such a use case in okhttp?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> this it always results in a network request and reading the response body

I don’t believe this is the case. OkHttp will honor 304s and return the cached response body. You can see this by looking at the cacheResponse and networkResponse fields of a conditional hit.

Comment: I thought the same. Initially, I was reading the code on how okhttp works with the cache and came across [this condition](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/acf873543f197283995232446a35fd8a83fad77e/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/cache/CacheStrategy.kt#L160). That is, with `no-cache` the `cacheResponse` is nulled, which always leads to a network request and the cache being ignored.

Comment: After I didn't find a suitable unit test [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/acf873543f197283995232446a35fd8a83fad77e/okhttp/src/test/java/okhttp3/CacheTest.java), I quickly set up a little infra to test this hypothesis and subsequent research. I'm making the [repository](https://github.com/mrblrrd/okhttp-cache-control-playground) public so you can see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> try to validate the cached response on origin server, if the server responds that it's still valid (304), then use it, but if there is no network, then you can use the cached response.

You could probably implement this feature as an application interceptor. Make a first call normally. If it throws, make a 2nd call with a Cache-Control header that’s very relaxed with respect to staleness. Throw in an only-if-cached parameter too!

We could probably implement this in OkHttp but I’d love for you to try it in the real world to see how it performs.

Comment: In fact, I'm already doing this. In my case, I additionally need to enable caching of POST responses due to the RPC-over-HTTP approach. I decided to ask a question to see if I could subsequently share something with the upstream regarding changes to `no-cache` and the implementation of `stale-if-error`. It was also interesting to know what you think about the current `no-cache` behavior. It's possible that I may have misunderstood something.